# [over.literal]/1 doesn't seem to be accurate

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, specifications, user-defined-literals

Definition of [*literal-operator-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#nt:literal-operator-id):

*literal-operator-id*:
    `operator` *string-literal identifier*
    `operator` *user-defined-string-literal*

[[over.literal]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#1)

> The *string-literal* or *user-defined-string-literal* in a *literal-operator-id* shall have no *encoding-prefix* and shall contain no characters other than the implicit terminating `'\0'`. The *ud-suffix* of the *user-defined-string-literal* or the *identifier* in a *literal-operator-id* is called a *literal suffix identifier*. Some literal suffix identifiers are reserved for future standardization; see [usrlit.suffix]. **A declaration whose *literal-operator-id* uses such a literal suffix identifier is ill-formed, no diagnostic required**.

AFAICT, the ill-formedness mentioned in the highlighted text above refers only to *literal-operator-ids* in *user-defined-string-literal*s. The *identifier* in the first definition of a *literal-operator-id* already satisfies the requirements explicited in [[usrlit.suffix]](http://eel.is/c++draft/usrlit.suffix) as they are identifiers used by the Standard Library, i.e., they don't start with underscores..

This is so confusing that I need to confirm this, or have someone to show me that I'm wrong.

Comment: `user-defined-string-literal` results in `string-literal identifier`...

Comment: maybe this should be a separate question, but isn't `operator` *string-literal* *identifier* redundant, seeing as *user-defined-string-literal* resolves to *string-literal* *identifier* anyway?

Comment: I don't really understand your question but it seems to me the bold text should say "A declaration whose *declarator-id* is a *literal-operator-id* which uses such a literal suffix...".  Otherwise `auto x = std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s(1);` would be ill-formed

Comment: @Jarod42 A _user-defined-string-literal_ does result in a _string-literal_  _identifier_, but this _identifier_ **has** to start with an underscore according to [usrlit.suffix], while a _string-literal_ used in the standard library (if there is one) doesn't start with an underscore, also by [ustrlit.suffix]. The first definition of the _literal-operator-id_ above refers to a "non-user-defined" _string-literal_, and the second definition is about a _user-defined-string-literal_. That's my interpretation of the two grammar productions.

Comment: @Jarod42 What I'm saying in relation to the highlighted sentence above is that it applies only to the _user-defined-string-literal_, simply because the first definition of the _literal-operator-id_, implicitly assumes that the _identifier_ doesn't start with an underscore.